# windows 2003 server read only access

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I'm having a read only access problem.  I have admin rights and can set the security for a folder to give me full access but when I switch the check box for read only off then exit out and open the properties back up it is checked.  It is a grayed out check box if that helps.  I just don't know how I have read/write access but can't switch off read only for a particular folder.

Thanks

Comment: I guess this question is more appropriate on Serverfault.com

Comment: That looks just to be an advertisement for one of those clean PC products.  As for the question I also tried to use attrib but every time it will hang and then say File not found.

Answer (score 0):

You should check further up the tree. On my install it was read only all the way from the root.